# Avoid Segmentation Fault with Empty Linked List

Tags: c, list, pointers, queue

I have a List in C with the following data structures:

```
typedef struct node{
    int in_id;
    struct node *next; 
} Node;

typedef struct List{
    Node* head;
    Node* tail;
}List;
```

My function for viewing the front of the list works fine if the list is occupied, however, if the list is empty and I take a peek inside the list, I receive a segmentation error.  Which is completely understandable.  However, I have been trying to think of a way to either prevent this or circumvent the segmentation error.

```
Node* front(List *q){
Node *temp;
temp = NULL;
if(q->head == NULL && q->tail == NULL){
    printf("front function: this is empty \n");
    return temp;
}
else{
    temp = q->head;
    return temp;
    }
}
```

First idea is if I need to use front in an `if(front(Node)->value == x)`, I get a segmentation error if its empty.  However, I short circuit this by putting something else I need to test before front, `if( something == TRUE && front(Node)->value == x)`. 
What I also thought about doing was `malloc()` some dynamic memory to `temp` within front and assigning the relevant field that I'm testing for a value that I know is false if the `head && tail == NULL`.  However, I feel this is memory leakage becuase I wouldn't be able to `free() temp`.

Is there a better way for me to handle peeking into this queue and not getting a segmentation fault if its empty?

Comment: TL;DR `if(q == NULL) { /* List is empty */ return NULL;}`

Comment: `if(!isEmpty(aList)  && front(aList)->value == x)`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY - This is how I short circuit this and avoid a segmentation fault.  But is there a way to handle `front()` so that I won't get a segmentation fault if I call it and its empty?

Comment: `front` may must return a `NULL`, So  does not use alone  `front(aList)->value`.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY - makes sense, i figured that there is really no way around not using it alone. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're trying to do too much in your one-liner function call.  `front(Node)->value` is always going to try to dereference whatever is returned from that function, even if it is `NULL`, hence the seg fault when the list is empty and it returns `NULL`.  You need to split that line up.. first retrieve the pointer from a call to `front(...)`, then check it for `NULL`, and if not `NULL`, then proceed with the dereference:

```
 Node* temp = front(list);
 if (temp != NULL)
 {
   // proceed with dereference
   if (temp->value == x) // this won't seg fault, do whatever with it
   {
      // ...
   }
 }
 else
 {
   // print error or do nothing
 }
```

There is probably a more clever way to one-line it, but if you're stuck and not constrained with a strict line requirement is it really worth it?

Comment: if you are determined to keep it a 1-liner, then you can do something like `if(front(list) && front(list)==x){`. Just be sure to watch order of operations here, the check for a valid return from `front` MUST be done before a dereference or you will have the same problem as before. And I'd be willing to bet this will get compiled into almost exactly the same as the original answer, so it won't gain you anything practical.

But just in general, get into a habit of checking for NULL from any function that may return that, one way or another. It will save you headaches. Either way is fine IMO.

Answer (score 0):

If the linked list is empty then head node is always null. And in your function your checking head and tail element of the empty node. that's why your getting segmentation fault .

just try below function

```
  Node* front(List *q){
  Node *temp;
  temp = NULL;
  if(q == NULL){
     printf("front function: this is empty \n");
     return temp;
   }
 else{
   temp = q->head;
    return temp;
   } 
 }
```

Comment: This doesn't quite work, I still get a segmentation fault.

Comment: Then you mast check whether your linked list getting form correctly or not

Comment: It gets the front correctly...but when it returns a NULL and tries to reference it...it's a segmentation fault.